# What is the difference between javax.swing.JInternalFrame and JInternalFrame in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I saw an example of `JInternalFrame` on the net, it was written like:

```
public class AddEntry extends JInternalFrame
```

When I tried to create a `JInternalFrame`  in Netbeans, it came  like:

```
public class NewJInternalFrame1 extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame
```

So, I'm not getting how to get `public class AddEntry extends JInternalFrame`. I have tried all option but it always came as  `javax.swing.JInternalFrame`.

Comment: `AddEntry extends JInternalFrame` very likely is the same as `AddEntry extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame` just with `JInternalFrame` being imported into the file (see import statements).

Answer (score 1):

As stated by the [`Java Documentation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html):

> To use a public package member from outside its package, you must do one of the following:
>
> - Refer to the member by its fully qualified name
> - Import the package member
> - Import the member's entire package

In both of the examples you provide the same class `JInternalFrame` is being used.

In the net case importing a package member:

```
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;

public class AddEntry extends JInternalFrame
```

In the Netbeans case referring to the member by its qualified name:

```
public class NewJInternalFrame1 extends javax.swing.JInternalFrame
```